# Incorrect SQL Syntax with nested Select statements in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Trying to create a Crystal Report and need to make my own custom dataset from our existing database to do so. I've done all the aliasing, checked that the individual selects are solid, but when I put them all together, I get syntax errors. Where am I going wrong? SQLexpress query here:

```
/*Enter date from month you wish to report on: (ex Jan 2015 would be 2015-01-xx)*/
SELECT 
AvgCompRespDays.CompDaysHigh,
AvgCompRespDays.CompDaysLow,
AvgCompRespDays.RespDaysHigh,
AvgCompRespDays.RespDaysLow,
TotalWO.Total,
TotalWO.Now,
TotalWO.High,
TotalWO.Low,
NumberMetGoal.High,
NumberMetGoal.Low,
TopTenTypes.Top10
FROM
(
/*    SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","CLSDDATE")*1.0) AS CompDaysNow,   AVG(DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","RESPONDEDDATE")*1.0) AS RespDaysNow
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'Now' 
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate}),*/

SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","CLSDDATE")*1.0) AS CompDaysHigh, AVG(DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","RESPONDEDDATE")*1.0) AS RespDaysHigh
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'High - 1 Day' 
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate}) /*these next two lines specify closed tickets in the last month*/
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate}),

SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","CLSDDATE")*1.0) AS CompDaysLow, AVG(DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","RESPONDEDDATE")*1.0) AS RespDaysLow
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'Low - 3 Days' 
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate})
) AS AvgCompRespDays,
(
SELECT COUNT("PRIORITY") AS Now
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'Now'
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate}),

SELECT COUNT("PRIORITY") AS High
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'High - 1 Day'
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate}),

SELECT COUNT("PRIORITY") AS Low
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'Low - 3 Days'
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate}),

SELECT COUNT("PRIORITY") AS Total
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate})
) AS TotalWO,
(
SELECT COUNT("PRIORITY") AS High
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","CLSDDATE") <= 1
AND "PRIORITY" = 'High - 1 Day'
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate}),

SELECT COUNT("PRIORITY") AS Low
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","CLSDDATE") <= 3
AND "PRIORITY" = 'Low - 3 Days'
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate})
) AS NumberMetGoal,
(
SELECT TOP 10 "TYPE",COUNT("TYPE") AS Top10
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
ORDER BY COUNT("TYPE") DESC
) AS TopTenTypes
```

Comment: You need to tell sql server how the derived tables connect to each other, either use joins between them or union all.

Comment: Can you use a table variable or CTE or is the above query generated from Crystal?  I think you'll need to refactor it a bit...it looks like you're trying to aggregate a number of different single-value results but then your last nested query will return multiple rows.  If you are doing this in a stored procedure that will get called then I would suggest breaking it down into smaller subpieces within your process and put it back together at the end.

To that - what do you expect your final data set to look like?

Comment: @PeterTirrell This is what I'm going for: https://imgur.com/8RbPxBM
The individual cells are what the queries are calculating, while top10 calculates the top10 list in the bottom right. Is this possible with unions?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, when I Unioned all, it told me there were errors with using AS. Here's the modified code: http://pastebin.com/cvKbe1S2

Comment: @russ, the error output is not very verbose; it doesn't tell me where the error is, only what caused it. Your guess is as good as mine. This is the most recent query to give that error: http://pastebin.com/cvKbe1S2

Comment: To me, all the double quotes seem the problem, you can delete these where they surround an object and it makes more sense...

Comment: Removed all of them and got the same error. It doesn't like AS, apparently!

Comment: Just to make sure, use 'find and replace' which is on the edit menu and replace " with space, you should get 162 occurences. also all the ?reportingDate references are in {} type brackets, I've never seen this in SQL Server so replace with [], unfotunately it seems the find and replace doesn't find the {} type brackets (on mine) so you can cut and paste into notepad and do it there.

Comment: You can't union like that. Please try to figure out what exactly it is you want to achieve , and what does your derived tables have in common.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I want to craft a query that contains all the information in that table. I've got queries for individual cells, but I want to put them all together.

Comment: @russ, I changed it but got the same error.

Comment: Like what Zohar is referring to, I think you're trying to do too much in a single query to get the results that you're trying to get; the SQL syntax you're trying just won't work that way.  Can you use separate data sets?  I'm going to try my hand at an answer that hopefully might point you in a good direction.

Comment: @PeterTirrell it doesn't need to be all at once, in fact I'd prefer it in a C-like struct that can be decomposed with the . operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do too much in a single query; from what I'm reading you're trying to get both single total data points, and then also a collection of top 10 results.  These are different things and I think at the very least you'll need to break these out into separate queries / data sets for pulling into Crystal.  It's been awhile since I've worked with Crystal, but if it's anything like SSRS you'd build your query and either make it into a stored proc or embed it inline and then in the report software create a dataset from that query.  So I'm envisioning you have a dataset for your top 10 list, and then a dataset with the individual total points that you can place wherever you want.

So first take your TOP 10 query and set that as it's own dataset:

```
SELECT TOP 10 "TYPE",COUNT("TYPE") AS Top10
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
ORDER BY COUNT("TYPE") DESC
```

Now for the individual data points I think the query can work as a Common Table Expression (CTE).  Something like:

```
;WITH AvgCompRespDaysHigh as (
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","CLSDDATE")*1.0) AS CompDaysHigh, AVG(DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","RESPONDEDDATE")*1.0) AS RespDaysHigh
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'High - 1 Day' 
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate}) /*these next two lines specify closed tickets in the last month*/
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate}))
),
AvgCompRespDaysLow as (SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","CLSDDATE")*1.0) AS CompDaysLow, AVG(DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","RESPONDEDDATE")*1.0) AS RespDaysLow
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'Low - 3 Days' 
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate})
),
TotalWONow as (
SELECT COUNT("PRIORITY") AS Now
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'Now'
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate})
),
TotalWOHigh as (SELECT COUNT("PRIORITY") AS High
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'High - 1 Day'
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate})
),
TotalWOLow as (SELECT COUNT("PRIORITY") AS Low
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'Low - 3 Days'
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate})
),
TotalWOTotal AS (SELECT COUNT("PRIORITY") AS Total
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate})
),
NumberMetGoalHigh AS (
SELECT COUNT("PRIORITY") AS High
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","CLSDDATE") <= 1
AND "PRIORITY" = 'High - 1 Day'
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate})

),
NumberMetGoalLow AS (SELECT COUNT("PRIORITY") AS Low
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","CLSDDATE") <= 3
AND "PRIORITY" = 'Low - 3 Days'
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate})
)

SELECT 
AvgCompRespDaysHigh.CompDaysHigh,
AvgCompRespDaysLow.CompDaysLow,
AvgCompRespDaysHigh.RespDaysHigh,
AvgCompRespDaysLow.RespDaysLow,
TotalWOTotal.Total,
TotalWONow.Now,
TotalWOHigh.High,
TotalWOLow.Low,
NumberMetGoalHigh.High,
NumberMetGoalLow.Low
FROM AvgCompRespDaysHigh, AvgCompRespDaysLow, TotalWOTotal, TotalWONow, TotalWOHigh, TotalWOLow, NumberMetGoalHigh, NumberMetGoalLow
```

But that still seems pretty clunky to me.  I also don't know where you're getting your field names and passed in variables, if that's a Crystal Reports thing or not.  Some of the other comments mentioned removing double quotes, etc.

If the data set you're finally looking for is just a single row with a field for each total, it might be more straightforward to make an @table variable with a field for each value you want, and then run each aggregate query updating the value in the table variable as appropriate.  Then you could just select back out that row and it saves some of the clumsiness of the above CTE.

Comment: How would I got about doing the table? That sounds like what I need (I think)

Comment: Something like this?

Something like this I think:  

    `DECLARE @OUTPUT TABLE (CompDaysHigh int,`
    `CompDaysLow int,`
    `RespDaysHigh int,`
    `RespDaysLow int,`
    `WOTotal int,`
    `WONow int,`
    `WOHigh int,`
    `WOLow int,`
    `NumberMetGoalHigh int,`
    `NumberMetGoalLow int)`  
    
    `INSERT INTO @OUTPUT SELECT blah value FROM...  `
    
    UPDATE @OUTPUT SET blahothercolumn  = value from next query

And then you can have your individual UPDATE statements continue on from there...